# Van der Waerden number - on a specific type of sequence

Tags: combinatorics

Here is the problem, as given

> Let $R_k$ be the set of increasing sequences $\{x_1<x_2<\ldots<x_k\}$ of length $k$ such that there are integers $a_3, a_4,\ldots,a_k$ (depending on the sequence) such that 
>   $$x_3=a_3x_2+(1-a_3)x_1, \ x_4=a_4x_3+(1-a_4)x_2,\ldots, \ x_k=a_kx_{k-1}+(1-a_k)x_{k-2}$$
>   Prove that every $2$ colouring of $[n]$ with $n \geq 7(k + 1)!/24$ contains a monochromatic member of $R_k$.

**Notations**

We denote $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

For simplicity, to compare with Van der Wearden numbers $W(2,k)$, I'll call $P(k)$ the minimum $n$ such that every $2$ colouring of $[n]$ contains a monochromatic sequence of $R_k$.

**Comments**

We can first notice that the case $a_i=2$ for all $i$ induces all artithmetic progressions. Therefore $P(k)<W(2,k)$.

We can also rewrite $R_k$ (I found it easier to read as follow, it might not be the case for everyone). In such a sequence $x_i$'s, the difference between two consecutive term $x_i-x_{i-1}$ is a divisor of the difference $x_i-x_{i-2}$. Each number in the sequence can be written in the form$$x_i=x_1+d\cdot r_i$$ with some constraints on the $r_i$. More precisely, $R_k$ is a set of sequence of the form $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k\}$ with

- $x_1$ is the initialisation,
- $x_2$ defines the difference $d=x_2-x_1$,
- and then there exist a set of constants $a_i\geq 2$ such that each $x_i$ can be written as
  $$x_i = x_{i-2}+d\cdot a_i\cdot\prod_{j=3}^{i-1}(a_j-1)$$
  Or equivalently
  $$x_i = x_{i-1}+d\cdot\prod_{j=3}^{i}(a_j-1)$$

**Visualization** : Therefore the sequence of $R_k$ are sequences of integers, where the difference of two consecutive number is a multiple of the difference between the two previous numbers:

$$\ldots x_i \overbrace{\qquad}^{\alpha} x_{i+1} \overbrace{\qquad}^{\alpha\beta}x_{i+2}\ldots$$

**Proof**: Now working on the actual problem, I think that induction might be a good way to start. Looking then at the **base case**, $k=3$. I need to show that for $n\geq 7$, for every colouring
$$\chi:[n]\rightarrow 2$$
there exists a monochromatric sequence from $R_3=\{(x,x+d,x+rd)\mid x\in[n],\ d\geq1, \ r\geq2\}$. 
This is easy enough by elimination (I don't write the details here, but noting that having two consecutive numbers with the same colouring is "bad", we know that 1,2,3,4 have alternating colors, then 5 must be colored as 2 and 4, 6 must be colored as 1,3, and whatever color for 7 will lead to a monochromatic sequence from $R_3$) .

**Induction**
This is where I fail. Suppose we have a colouring of $n'=\frac{7(k+2)!}{24}$. I think a good way to start is to split $[n']$ as follow
$$\underbrace{[n], \ [n]+n, \ [n]+2n,\ldots, \ [n]+(k+1)n}_{(k+2)\text{ terms}}$$
With $n=\frac{7(k+1)!}{24}$. Therefore in each term, I know that there exist a monochromatic sequence from $R_k$. Even more, for every constant $c$, the set $\{c+1,c+2,\ldots,c+n\}$ contains a monochromatic sequence of $R_k$.

I should be able to construct the sequence from $R_{k+1}$ from theses sequences, but I'm not sure to see how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n_k=\frac{7(k+1)!}{24}$. Suppose that for a given $k$, any 2-colouring of $[n_k]$ contains a monochromatic sequence from $R_k$. Suppose we have a colouring of $[n_{k+1}]$.

By induction hypothesis, in $[n_k]$ there exist a monochromatic sequence $\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}$ from $R_k$, w.l.g make it red.

Let $d=x_k-x_{k-1}$, the last difference in our original sequence. Because the $\{x_i\}$'s sequence is in $[n_k]$, we have $d<n(k)$. Let define 
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
y_1=x_k+d\\
y_i=x_k+id=y_{i-1}+d&\text{ for }i=1,\ldots,k+1\\
\end{array}\right.$$

Note that $n_{k+1}=\frac{7(k+2)!}{24}=n_k\cdot(k+2)$, therefore 
$$y_{k+1}=x_k+(k+1)d < (k+2)n_k=n_{k+1}$$
 and 
$$\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,k+1\}, \ y_i \in [n_{k+1}]$$

If for any $i$, $y_i$ is red, then we are done as the sequence $\{x_1,\ldots,x_k,y_i\}$ is a sequence of $R_{k+1}$. If they are all blue, then the sequence $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^{k+1}$ is a monochromatic $(k+1)$-arithmetic progression  (with common difference $d$) in $[n_{k+1}]$, proving the induction step.

Therefore every $2$-colouring of $[n]$ with $n \geq \frac{7(k + 1)!}{24}$ contains a monochromatic member of $R_k$.